# The relation between surface charge density to wave reflection

Tags: electromagnetism, reflection, gauss-law, metals

We know from Guass law that if an electric field hit perpendicular from dielectric medium to a metal, then a charge density develops on the surface.

$D_{in} - D_{hit} = \sigma$

Where in metal the Din=0 so

$ - D_{hit} = \sigma$

$ \sigma = -\epsilon_0 \epsilon _r \cdot E_{in}$

So, we get a connection between the charge density to the hitting perpendicular electric field.

From electromagnetism theory we know that when an incident wave hitting a metal plate there must be a reflected wave to keep the electric field inside the metal is 0.

The two theories dealing with incident electric field hitting the metal plate, but their consequences are different.

So, what is really happening when electric field hitting perpendicular to a metal plate? is it reflected back or is the metal develops a charge density?

Comment: The answer depends on what value you have for $\epsilon_r$ and $\mathcal K$ (conductivity) at the RF (microwave) frequency.

Comment: can you give a general answer? in term of ϵr and K and $ \omega $

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations (you must use *complex* $\epsilon$ to include conductivity)